# Pycharm Couldn't connect to console process

Tags: python, pycharm, caffe, pycaffe

I recently installed Caffe along with OpenCV and other dependencies. Pycharm worked well for 2 days and today I can't start Python Console in Pycharm anymore. I can start python in terminal with no problem... Everytime I try to start a Python Console it will take a while to "connecting to console" and then this is what I get after:

> /Users/myname/anaconda/bin/python "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py" 56229 56230
>
> Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:04:42) 
>   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
>   Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
>   Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>
> Couldn't connect to console process.
>
> Process finished with exit code 137

Comment: Raise this as an issue at the [PyCharm bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Answer (score 0):

I solved going on Settings/Project: [YourProjectName]/Project Interpreter and changing it to python.exe from the dropdown menu. I don't know why but there was a different one by default.

Answer (score -4):

I had this problem running interpreter in Docker. Checking "Import credentials from Docker Machine" in Build->Execution->Deployment->Docker solved that.

Answer (score -4):

this might be your firewall prevent the pycharm, please check the firewall.

Comment: Please add how to check it